# QGIS tiff image loaded but not visible

Tags: qgis, raster, georeferencing

In QGIS I used the Georeferencer on a jpg image I had prepared in Gimp.  But when I load the resulting tiff image into my QGIS project it is invisible, even though an image viewing program can show it perfectly well.  I used exactly the same method to georeference a jpg image of an OS sheet covering the same area, and that shows up perfectly well in QGIS.

Why is my second layer invisible?

Comment: Can you add more information about the exact steps you are taking to produce this issue?

Comment: Try `gdalinfo your_geotiff` from the command line to check georeference data, try to zoom the layer extent.

Comment: The advice about gdalinfo is helpful for the future, but meanwhile  I found a solution - or rather a work-around - to my problem.
Although I set the SRS correctly in the Transformation Settings dialogue
of the Georeferencer, when I look in the properties for the new layer in
QGIS, the CRS is wrong.  By correcting it in the Properties dialogue,
the problem disappears - i.e. the layer does appear!  I'm using QGIS
2.8.2 on Ubuntu Linux 12.04.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: I right-clicked the layer, chose "Set Layer CRS", set it to EPSG:3857, and bang! it showed up. The rest of my project is in EPSG:32719 (a UTM projection). Maybe there's some kind of issue with georeferencing in a UTM projection. Someone else will have to explain why this happens.

Comment: @DavidSumbler please write your comment as an answer. Please do not include thanks when you do.

Comment: I had the same issue in qgis 3.8 and also qgis 3.16.9 and 3.20.1 on windows. In the end, the layer appeared after switching between different projections as @ErikMarsh wrote.